# How to write a customize annotation and process that

Tags: java, annotations

I want to create a customized annotaion in java. like @Myannotation(name="thrinod", value="Man")
Based on that created annotaion i need to process the annotation and retrieve the values which are given  for that annotaion at runtime.

Comment: How can I process my custom annotation ? this was my question. For the answer see below....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation is a kind of meta data. To Process the annotation, we need to use `Reflection API of JSE`. Here is one customize annotation that I am processing. Please see the below.

```
@Documented
    @Retention(value=RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(value={ElementType.METHOD})
    public @interface SK08{
       public String name() default "SK08";
    }

Annotation Processing in Java Class:
=====================================
public class POJO {
    private String name;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    @SK08(name="Bangalore")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

Processing class
==================
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        POJO pojo = new POJO();
        setValue(pojo);
    }

    private static void setValue(POJO pojo) {
        for (Method method: pojo.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
            for (Annotation annotation : method.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
                if(annotation instanceof SK08){
                    System.out.println(((SK08)annotation).name());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```